# Error connecting GCP App Engine to GCP SQL

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to deploy a Flask App on the App Engine, but I'm getting this error about the database connection:

> sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (2003,
> "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' ([Errno 111] Connection
> refused)")

I'm doing the connection like this:

> databaseUri = 'mysql+pymysql://user:pass@/database?unix_socket=/cloudsql/connection_name'

Also activated the **Cloud SQL Administrator API** as the documentation says, but not working

Does anyone have an idea about what am I missing or doing wrong?

I've have been stuck on this for 2 days and I can't make it work, thanks for your help.

Comment: which is it - trying to deploy the app or trying to run it on dev (local host)? Is this GAE Standard or is this GAE Flexible? Did you see this - https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-app-engine-standard

Comment: Can you provide a sample code that we could reproduce?

Comment: In addition, check if your configuration is correct like your `instance-name`, `db-user`, `db-password` and/or `db-name`. It would be better if you provide your `app.yaml` file together with your sample code that we could reproduce. Please redact any sensitive information before posting your `yaml` file.

Answer (score 2):

I solved it.

I post the solution maybe helps someone else.

I still don't know why, but when running the command to deploy the app in the App Engine:

```
gcloud app deploy
```

It use by default the Compute Engine service account instead of the App Engine service account, so I just had to run the command specifying it to use the App Engine service account:

```
gcloud app deploy --service-account=SERVICE_ACCOUNT
```

Hope it helps any newbe like me.